# Can't get OpenCover to work in fake

Tags: f#, f#-fake

EDITED to show the ignore return as pointed out by Fyodor and the resulting error

I have a `.fsx` file with several targets that work as expected, but I can't get a target for `OpenCover` to work. This is what I have for the Target code:

```
Target "Coverage" (fun _ ->
  OpenCover
    (fun p -> { p with ExePath   = "./packages/OpenCover.4.6.519/tools/OpenCover.Console.exe"
                   TestRunnerExePath = "./packages/Machine.Specifications.Runner.Console.0.10.0-Unstable0005/tools/mspec-clr4.exe"
                   Output = reportDir + "MspecOutput.xml"
                   Register = "-register:user"
          }
    )
    testDir @@ "FakeTest2UnitTesting.dll" + "--xml " + reportDir + "MspecOutput.xml"  |> ignore
)
```

But I now get the following build error:

> build.fsx(45,3): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'OpenCover' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following:
>              OpenCoverHelper
>              NCover

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can someone show me how to use the OpenCoverHelper from the [FAKE API](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-opencoverhelper.html)?
Thanks

Comment: The function `OpenCover` returns a string (which I assume contains the output), and you're not doing anything with it. You need to either log it or explicitly ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of playing around an googling, I finally came up with the solution. The basic problem was that I didn't open the `OpenCoverHelper`. I made the assumption that it was included in FAKE as it is in the Api and there was no documentation saying anything else. So, here is the code I use:

```
// include Fake lib
#r @"packages/FAKE.4.61.2/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake
open Fake.OpenCoverHelper

Target "Coverage" (fun _ ->
  OpenCover (fun p -> { p with 
                          ExePath = "./packages/OpenCover.4.6.519/tools/OpenCover.Console.exe"
                          TestRunnerExePath = "./packages/Machine.Specifications.Runner.Console.0.10.0-Unstable0005/tools/mspec-clr4.exe"
                          Output = "./report/MspecOutput.xml"
                          Register = RegisterUser
                      })
   "./test/FakeTest2UnitTesting.dll + --xml ./report/MspecOutput.xml"
```

)

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.